# Cant create google charts

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a page wherein I have 2 inputs and both are inserted into a database table.

Table has 2 columns: Assets(text) and amount(number)

I want to create a pie chart on a different page with the values that were inserted into the table.

When I load the below page it displays nothing. :( Just a blank page.

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Pie Chart Demo (Google VAPI) - http://codeofaninja.com/</title>
    </head>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <!-- where the chart will be rendered -->
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <?php

    //include database connection
    include 'connection.php';

    //query all records from the database
    $query = "select * from financial";

    //execute the query
    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );

    //get number of rows returned
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;

    if( $num_results > 0){

    ?>
        <!-- load api -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jsapi.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //load package
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function drawVisualization() {
                // Create and populate the data table.
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Assets', 'Amount'],
                    <?php
                    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                        extract($row);
                        echo "['{$assets}', {$amount}],";
                    }
                    ?>
                ]);

                // Create and draw the visualization.
                new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(data, {title:"Sample"});
            }

            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
        </script>
    <?php

    }else{
        echo "Error.";
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```